# saving newtonsoft json response to isolatedstorage?

Tags: json, isolatedstorage

how can I save a list of Objects to isolatedstorage which is returned from a json call,

I already parse the result into a list of Objects, but I cannot seem to save it, I got a few xmlserialization issues, then I tried following this:
    [How to save a list of objects in isolated storage in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016613/how-to-save-a-list-of-objects-in-isolated-storage-in-wp7)

but it led to a error

{System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: You must implement a default accessor on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject because it inherits from ICollection.

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of the code that caused this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Opted to do the following:

```
private static void SerialiseAsJson(string textToSave, string fileName)
{
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"..\..\NinjectModules\Fakes\FakeData\" + fileName))
   {
       file.WriteLine(textToSave);   
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
SerialiseAsJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject([object to serialize]),"filename.JSon");
```